# Selecting values based on MIN and MAX(Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to query the channel type(MAIL, TELEMARKETING OR WEB) associated with the most recent, and the earliest dates of customer enrollment.

Right now my query reads

```
SELECT CustomerID, MIN(DateAttempt) AS EarliestAttempt, MAX(DateAttempt) AS MostRecentAttempt
FROM EnrollmentAttempt
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

And it gives me a table which displays;

```
CustomerID                      MostRecentAttempt   EarliestAttempt
094B7C82-12DC-4797-905C-9041752E0975    2018-03-04  2017-12-15
1C1C0DC7-C4D2-4C1B-A9DE-79865700B444    2017-03-09  2017-03-09
60186ED6-DDAF-4D14-BEBB-45AF9CBF0F07    2018-02-12  2015-05-09
A2A1657E-9C79-44E6-98DB-277269965579    2018-03-15  2017-05-01
FE344C8F-8B7A-4FCB-9129-C20127627345    2018-01-04  2016-05-03
```

I need 2 more columns in this table, Channel type for the enrollment on MAX(DateAttempt), and Channel type for enrollment on MIN(DateAttempt).

The table EnrollmentAttempt is below;;

```
Channel       DateAttempt          CustomerID
mail          2017-05-01       A2A1657E-9C79-44E6-98DB-277269965579
mail          2018-02-01       A2A1657E-9C79-44E6-98DB-277269965579
web        2018-03-15      A2A1657E-9C79-44E6-98DB-277269965579
telemarketing   2017-11-02    60186ED6-DDAF-4D14-BEBB-45AF9CBF0F07
web         2018-02-12    60186ED6-DDAF-4D14-BEBB-45AF9CBF0F07
mail           2015-05-09      60186ED6-DDAF-4D14-BEBB-45AF9CBF0F07
telemarketing   2017-03-09     1C1C0DC7-C4D2-4C1B-A9DE-79865700B444
mail            2018-03-04  094B7C82-12DC-4797-905C-9041752E0975
web           2017-12-15    094B7C82-12DC-4797-905C-9041752E0975
telemarketing   2016-05-03  FE344C8F-8B7A-4FCB-9129-C20127627345
mail             2018-01-04 FE344C8F-8B7A-4FCB-9129-C20127627345
```

Comment: Please give the whole table structure (EnrollementAttempt) to know what channel means and ideally a raw sample with the expected result would be good to be able to help you. There is nothing about channel visible in your question except the three columns mentioned in your query result.

Comment: Just pasted the table I am querying from. It has 3 columns Channel (mail, web, or telemarketing), DateAttempt, and CustomerID. Customers can enroll more than once. The query needs to pull the earliest enrollment attempt, most recent enrollment attempt, and what the channel was for each of those. I need two more columns in the results table.

Comment: Using tsql-- microsoft sql management studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server

Comment: Do you have a Customer table, where CustomerID is a PK?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH mx AS (
    SELECT CustomerID, DateAttempt, Channel,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DateAttempt DESC) AS rn
    FROM EnrollmentAttempt
), mn AS (
    SELECT CustomerID, DateAttempt, Channel,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY DateAttempt) AS rn
    FROM EnrollmentAttempt
)
SELECT *
FROM mx INNER JOIN mn ON mn.CustomerID = mx.CustomerID
WHERE mx.rn = 1 AND mn.rn = 1;
```

This is indeed a greatest n per group problem. Trick is you need to do it twice and combine the results.

I've put both of the answers together for you to test. Note that the subquery method will break if there is the possibility of multiple attempts per date. And while the `row_number()` approach won't error, the result you get will be arbitrary. Adding channel to the list of ordering columns might let you repair that behavior for two attempts in a day, that won't be sufficient to handle a third or more.

http://rextester.com/edit/XENM75924

Comment: Is there a way to use partition and get the results in one query?

Comment: @kaysuez Technically, yes, but why do you need it that way?

Comment: I added a third method to my link. It uses an old hack with string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but it will work:

```
SELECT CustomerID, 
       MIN(DateAttempt) AS EarliestAttempt, 
       MAX(DateAttempt) AS MostRecentAttempt,
       (SELECT Channel FROM EnrollmentAttempt WHERE CustomerID = E.CustomerID AND DateAttempt = (SELECT MIN(DateAttempt) 
                            FROM EnrollmentAttempt 
                            WHERE  CustomerID = E.CustomerID)
       ) AS ChannelMin,
       (SELECT Channel FROM EnrollmentAttempt WHERE CustomerID = E.CustomerID AND DateAttempt = (SELECT MAX(DateAttempt) 
                            FROM EnrollmentAttempt 
                            WHERE  CustomerID = E.CustomerID)
       ) AS ChannelMax
FROM EnrollmentAttempt E
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tJsvyvhbq3c717VW9mQWFu/0)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't reference by alias in the subquery.

Comment: @shawnt00 You're right, I'm just checking in fiddle and looking for another way...

Comment: You should be able to correlate on the min/max expression itself. Just make sure to add the `e.` to qualify it.

Comment: Ok. I guess MySQL won't allow the top level expression. SQL Server seems fine though: http://rextester.com/XENM75924

Comment: It does seem to work in this MySQL fiddle though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e2d3a/1

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` to do this, I have made the assumption that you have a `Customer` table. If you do not you can still use the solution, you will just have to modify to use `GROUP BY` or `UNIQUE`.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, min.Channel, min.DateAttempt, max.Channel, max.DateAttempt
FROM Customer c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM EnrollmentAttempt
             WHERE CustomerID = c.CustomerID
             ORDER BY DateAttempt ASC) min
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM EnrollmentAttempt
             WHERE CustomerID = c.CustomerID
             ORDER BY DateAttempt DESC) max
```